# Tree hierarchy in Bash

Tags: bash, recursion, tree

I'm trying to implement a function in bash which displays a tree of files/directories for the given depth. It takes 3 arguments.

```
$1 = *current directory*
$2 = *current depth*
$3 = *lines*
```

for example, if my current directory is ".../living/", my depth is 2, my function should output:

```
DIR .../living/
----DIR animals
--------FILE dog
--------FILE cat
----DIR plants
--------FILE flowers
```

As you can see, the number of lines is increased by 4 for each depth change. The type of file (DIR, FILE) is not the question of this thread.
Here's what I have so far:

```
function tree {
    #some code to get the directory in variable cwd
    ...
    a=$(getType $cwd)
    echo "$a $cwd"
    depth=3 #the value does not matter, it's just for you guys to see
    drawTree $cwd $depth "----"
}

function drawTree {
    if [[ $2 == 0 ]]; then
         return
    fi

    dat=$1
    list=$(ls $dat)
    depth=$2
    lines=$3

    for d in $list; do
        f="$dat/$d"
        t=$(getType $f)
        echo "$lines$t $d"
        if [[ $t == "DIR" ]]; then
            g=$(($depth-1))
            l="$lines----"
            if [[ $g > 00 ]]; then
                drawTree $f $g $l
            fi
        fi
    done
```

The output of this code is sadly false and I have no idea why.

Comment: Quote your variables, "$var_whatever", use array to avoid some problems,... too many things to fix -- sorry. Suggested reading: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: I tend to disagree with suggesting the ABS as a reference -- it doesn't take particularly much care to filter poor practices from its suggestions. http://shellcheck.net/, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ may be better starting places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with that code.

The most serious is that your variables are not made local (see `help local`) which can be disastrous in a recursive function. In the loop in `drawtree`, the second iteration will see unwanted modifications to `$depth` and `$lines`, both of which will cause the output to be incorrect in different ways.

Also:

```
g=$(($depth-1))
l="$lines----"
if [[ $g > 00 ]]; then
    drawTree $f $g $l
fi
```

would much better be written without so many unnecessary variables, and using arithmetic rather than string comparison:

```
if (( depth > 1 )); then
   drawTree $f $((depth - 1)) ${lines}----
fi
```

Finally:

```
list=$(ls $dat)
for d in $list; do
```

will fail disastrously if there is whitespace or a shell metacharacter in a filepath. Much better is the use of a bash array and glob expansion rather than the `ls` command):

```
# Create an array from a glob 
list=("$dat"/*)
# Use the elements of the array, individually quoted:
for d in "${list[@]}"; do
```